# Simple DFS code doesnt work in Class form while working well in function form

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have no idea why my code does not work with my class-using form.

```py
k = 0

def dfs(m, n):
  global k
  if (m == 0) or (n == 0):
    k += 1
    return
  
  else:
    dfs(m - 1, n)
    dfs(m, n - 1)

dfs(2,1)

## Result : 3
```

The code above works well but-

```py
class Solution(object):
    def uniquePaths(self, m, n):
        """
        :type m: int
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        self.path = 0

        self.dfs(m - 1, n - 1)
        return self.path

    def dfs(self, m, n):

      if (m == 0) or (n == 0):
        self.path += 1
        return
      
      else:
        dfs(m - 1, n)
        dfs(m, n - 1)

ans = Solution().uniquePaths(3, 2)
print(ans)

## Result : 0
```

when I turn it into class-using code, the result is not the same with previous one.

Whould u guys tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are calling `dfs` recursively doesn't change the fact that it is a method and needs to be called as such. (There is no globally defined name `dfs`, only a class attribute of `Solution` named `dfs`.)

```
def dfs(self, m, n):

  if (m == 0) or (n == 0):
    self.path += 1
    return
  
  else:
    self.dfs(m - 1, n)
    self.dfs(m, n - 1)
```

Comment: I was doing something studpid :( Thanks A LOT!!!